# Bash Recursive Loop searching for file

Tags: bash, unix, recursion, directory, find

Our assignment was just a conditional statement to say if a file exists or doesn't in the current directory. I already completed the primary objective but I am just trying to figure out how I could recurse using a loop and finding any other occurrences of the file name.

**Currently, I am getting an infinite loop after finding the file in the first directory.**

File exists and is located at /home/charlie/file.txt

File exists and is located at /home/charlie/file.txt
...

**Questions:

1. Would I need to have a nested for loop somewhere even though I am recursively calling the function?
2. Does using $pwd mess it up as I am trying to step into the directories?
3. Why is it printing twice as of now?**

   #!/bin/bash

   ```
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
                echo 'Usage: findFile_new.sh [file name]'
                    exit 0
    fi

    exist="File exists and is located at "

    function check() {

    for file in $(pwd)/*
    do
            if [ -d "$file" ]; then

                    check $file $1

            else
                    ## Look for file
                    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
                            echo $exist$(pwd)/$1
                    fi
            fi
    done
    }

    check $1
   ```

Comment: Trying to work through this mentally. I think there might be an issue with how I am calling my check funciton? 

Something to do with it not getting the sub-directory when i call it?

Answer (score 0):

Getting closer....
Why am i getting this as my output????

File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//@/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//compareQuiz.sh/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/*/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//dir1/dir2/file.txt/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//dir1/dir2/testFile.txt/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//findFile_new.sh/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//testFile.txt/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//testscript.sh/*testFile.txt
File exists and is located at
/home/charlie//~/*testFile.txt

```
   #!/bin/bash

   if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
            echo 'Usage: findFile_new.sh [file name]'
                exit 0
fi

exist="File exists and is located at "

echo $1 $2



function check() {

for file in $1/*
do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then

                check $file $2

        else
                ## Look for file
                if [ -f "$2" ]; then
                        echo $exist$file
                fi
        fi
done
}

check $1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search is not truly recursive and will eventually fall into an infinite loop.
Rolling your own Bash script that would cover every case for recursive search within a directory - can be tricky (permission handling and links come to mind...)

What you could do - is to use `find` which takes care of all recursive woes, and then extract the data you may need. The script (or single command really) would be `find . -iname $1`

`find` `.` (in this directory) `-iname` match this name and ignore case and `$1` first arg value.
From the above you could `grep` to extract any data you may need.

I know this does not answer your question 1:1, but if you're just starting with Bash, I'd say you're better off using tools provided within Bash first, then trying rolling your own.
As your task was already accomplished and it's more of a general question, I figured I'd provide you with "what I would do". :)

Another point - when using `$pwd` - this being a bash reserved environment variable, it's better to use $PWD. It makes it simple to understand which env_vars are user declared and which are system reserved.

edit:
If you'd like to see a nice example of how this can be done, please checkout https://www.shellscript.sh/eg/directories/#traverse2.sh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are almost there. A possible problem is the variable `$file`
will contain pathname to the file such as `path/to/the/testFile.txt` while
the variable `$2` may contain only `testFile.txt`.

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: check path targetname
check() {
    local file
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        if [[ -d $file ]]; then
            check "$file" "$2"
        elif [[ -f $file && ${file##*/} = $2 ]]; then
            echo "found: $file"
        fi
    done
}

if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo "usage: $0 path name"
    exit 0
fi

check "$1" "$2"
```

The expression `${file##*/}` removes the pathname preceding the rightmost slash
inclusive and now you can compare it with `$2`.